# Returning a string array from a model as all lowercase

Tags: arrays, swift, string, model-view-controller

I have a basic data model that returns an array of string arrays. I need to be able to return all of the string arrays as lowercased. Here is the Model I am working with:

```
struct MyData {
    static func returnAllData(lowercase: Bool) -> [Model] {
        return [
            Model(stringArray: [”Hello”, There”]),
            Model(stringArray: [“World”, “Fu”, “Bar”])
        ]
    }
}
```

I've added that lowercase parameter. I just don't know how to tie in that parameter to the controller so that it displays the array of strings  depending on what the Bool is (either lowercase, or normal case).

Here's what I am using in the controller to get the data from the above model:

```
var allStrings = MyData.returnAllData(lowercase: true)
// but currently... this parameter doesn't do anything.
```

Any help on how I can use that parameter to make all the strings from returnAllData lowercase or normal case would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your struct like this :

**Method 1**

```
struct MyData {
    static func returnAllData(lowercase: Bool) -> [Model] {
        return [
            Model(stringArray: ["Hello", "There"].map { lowercase ? $0.lowercased() : $0 }),
            Model(stringArray: ["World", "Fu", "Bar"].map { lowercase ? $0.lowercased() : $0 })
        ]
    }
}
```

**Method 2**

```
struct MyData {
    static func returnAllData(lowercase: Bool) -> [Model] {
        return [
            Model(stringArray: ["Hello", "There"], lowercase: lowercase),
            Model(stringArray: ["World", "Fu", "Bar"], lowercase: lowercase)
        ]
    }
}

struct Model {
    var stringArray : [String]

    init(stringArray: [String], lowercase: Bool) {
        self.stringArray = stringArray.map { lowercase ? $0.lowercased() : $0 }
    }
}
```